# MVC 5 application - Help in code optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an html page where I need to render 3 tables with the data stored in datatable. I am pulling the data from a model and then writing my view in html.. I have 3 different datatables - primary, secondary, other. The only thing I change in the table code is the model name(code for primary below). How can I optimize this instead of rewriting the code for all 3 individually? TIA for your help.

```
<table id="primary" class="display" style="overflow:hidden !important;">
        @if (Model.PrimaryFunction != null)
        {
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn column in (Model.PrimaryFunction as DataTable).Columns)
                    {
                        @if (column.ColumnName.ToUpper().Contains("STEP TITLE"))
                        {
                            <th style="max-width:200px;">@column.ColumnName.ToUpper()</th>
                        }
                        else if (column.ColumnName.ToUpper().Contains("STEP #"))
                        {
                            <th style="white-space:nowrap;">@column.ColumnName.ToUpper()</th>//header row
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <th class="select-filter">@column.ColumnName.ToUpper()</th>//header row
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if ((Model.PrimaryFunction as DataTable).Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in (Model.PrimaryFunction as DataTable).Rows)
                    {
                        int count = 0;
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (DataColumn column in (Model.PrimaryFunction as DataTable).Columns)
                            {
                                if (count < 2)
                                {
                                    <td style="background-color:antiquewhite;">
                                        @dr[column].ToString()
                                    </td>//write one row at a time.
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td style="text-align:center !important;">
                                        @dr[column].ToString()
                                    </td>//write one row at a time.
                                }
                                count++;

                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var count = (Model.PrimaryFunction as DataTable).Columns.Count;
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='@count' style="color:red;">
                            No Data Found.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="color:red;">
                    @(Model.PrimaryFunction.HasErrors != false ? Model.PrimaryFunction.HasErrors.ToString() : "")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: You could use a `DataSet` object as your `Model` property, then place each of your 3 datatables inside of your dataset, return the model with a dataset instead of the 3 datatables and iterate the dataset doing your logic for all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different approach. Used partial view.. passed in parameter to the partial view and called it in the main view. This resolved it as well.

```
<div id="table1">
    @Html.Partial("_PopulateTable", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "table", "table1" } })

</div>
<div id="table2">
    @Html.Partial("_PopulateTable", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "table", "table2" } })

</div>
<div id="table3">
    @Html.Partial("_PopulateTable", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "table", "table3" } })
</div>
```